# Duda de multihilos en Java

Tags: java, hilos

Tengo aqui un ejercicio llamado Parking.
Lo entiendo ligeramente, pero hay una cosa que no me queda clara, y me refiero al parametro que lleva `Semaphore sem = new Semaphore(este_parametro_me_refiero)`.
Agradezco la ayuda!
Os dejo el codigo:

```
package ejercicio6_Parking;

import java.util.concurrent.Semaphore;

public class Coche implements Runnable{

    private Semaphore sem;
    private int numeroCoche;

    public Coche(int numeroCoche, Semaphore sem) {
        this.numeroCoche = numeroCoche;
        this.sem = sem;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Arranca el coche " + numeroCoche);
        while(true) {
            //el coche va por la ciudad entre 1 y 30s e intenta entrar al parking
            try {
                Thread.sleep( (long) (Math.random()*30000) );
                System.out.println("El coche " + numeroCoche + " llega al parking e intenta entrar.");
                sem.acquire();
                    System.out.println("El coche " + numeroCoche + " entra.");
                    Thread.sleep( (long) (Math.random()*30000));
                    System.out.println("El coche " + numeroCoche + " sale.");
                    System.out.println(sem.availablePermits() + " plazas libres.");
                    System.out.println(sem.getQueueLength() + " coches en la cola.");
                sem.release();
            }catch(InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }


}


package ejercicio6_Parking;

import java.util.concurrent.Semaphore;

public class Principal {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Semaphore sem = new Semaphore(0);
        for(int i=0; i<40; i++) {
            Coche c = new Coche(i+1, sem);
            Thread th = new Thread(c);
            th.start();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Puedes ver en la API la **documetación de la clase Semaphore**: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html hay un ejemplo explicado, eso si todo en inglés. Saludos.

Comment: Agradezco el aporte pero por lo general cada vez que miro una pagina como esa no me resuelve nada, solo liarme aun más.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para empezar, en java un semáforo lo que hace es permitirnos de una forma sencilla dar permisos a los hilos para acceder a los recursos.

El parámetro que tu le pasas al objeto `Semaphore` es el número de hilos que pueden acceder de forma simultanea a un recurso. Por ejemplo imagina que quiero acceder a un archivo pero solo quiero que puedan entrar como mucho 4 hilos de forma simultanea. Pues al crear el objeto `Semaphore` debería ser tal que

```
Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore(4);
```

Los metodos `acquire` y `release` son metodos para indicar cuando un hilo está en proceso y cuando ha terminado para permitir al resto de hilos (si lo requieren) acceder a dicho recurso.

Comment: Muchas gracias! Ahora si que me ha quedado claro :)

Comment: Me alegro que te haya aclarado como funciona ^^. Un saludo.

Answer (score 1):

El parametro de inicialización de esa clase, lo que indica es las veces que permitira acceder en este caso al parking(llamado sin bloqueo a `acquire`), si colocas 2, dejara llamar al método `acquire` 2 veces, el cual permitira pasar a 2 coches, una vez que esos 2 coches tengan ocupado las plazas, las llamadas próximas bloquearan a los hilos y esperaran la llamada release de los hilos que ocuparon las plazas del parking, los cuales digamos liberarian las plazas del parking.

en tu metodo main, tienes el for que genera varias instancias de tu clase Coche, que contienen el metodo run, y cada coche le pasas la misma instancia de `sem`

```
Semaphore sem = new Semaphore(0);
for(int i=0; i<40; i++) {
    Coche c = new Coche(i+1, sem);
    Thread th = new Thread(c);
    th.start();
}
```

dentro del metodo run, en tu clase `Coche`,

```
sem.acquire();
    System.out.println("El coche " + numeroCoche + " entra.");
    Thread.sleep( (long) (Math.random()*30000));
    System.out.println("El coche " + numeroCoche + " sale.");
    System.out.println(sem.availablePermits() + " plazas libres.");
    System.out.println(sem.getQueueLength() + " coches en la cola.");
sem.release();
```

cuando cada instancia alcanza a llamar la instrucción `sem.acquire();`, pueden ocurrir dos cosas, obtener una llamada bloqueante(que el semaforo no tenga "espacio" para permitir esa llamada, incrementando un contador para no sobrepasar el número `permits` que es el parametro de inicialización de la clase `Semaphore`) o una llamada no bloqueante (la cantidad de llamados `acquire` no ha sobrepasado el número de `permits`). Por lo que si inicializo `Semaphore sem = new Semaphore(4);`, los primeros 4 hilos que hagan la llamada `acquire` podran seguir ejecutandose, continuar con las instrucciones debajo de `acquire`, los hilos que lleguen en 5ta, 6ta, ... posición, se bloquearan (tendran que esperar a los hilos que continuaron ejecutandose normalmente hasta que alcanzen el llamado `sem.release()`, liberar espacios en el semaforo), una vez que se liberen espacios en el semaforo la ejecución de los hilos que estan en espera podran continuar, siempre y cuando haya "espacio para ellos"(llamadas no bloqueantes).

Comment: "El parametro de inicialización del esa clase" espera qué? O.o

Comment: Gracias por los comentarios, pero sigo sin entenderlo. Es un poco raro :S

Comment: haber ahora...?